# Internet statistics resources suitable for psychology  students doing research

Tags: spss, psychology, internet

I am working on a new webpage for my part-time job as a methodological/statistical consultant for (psychology) students at my university. On this website I would like to place several links to online recourses for clients to consult themselves.

So I am looking for links to websites that offer a lot of statistical information. Preferably written in a way that is easy to comprehend. Most students use SPSS, but information on other programs is welcome too.

So far I have:

- www.crossvalidated.com
- www.statmethods.net

Comment: What kind of students are they? i.e., Are they students doing statistics 101 or are they students doing their own research project and needing advice on how to conduct their analyses for their research project?

Comment: Mainly students doing their research projects.

Answer (score 10):

In general, encouraging research students to use Google and sites like [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) to ask and answer their own questions is important.

#### Specific Sites

- [Andy Field](http://www.statisticshell.com/apf.html) is famous for making statistics more palatable for psychology students. He provides many online resources generally with a focus on SPSS.
- [UCLA Statistics Consulting](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/) has many useful resources.
- [@chl has many good statistics resources](http://www.aliquote.org/) with a psychology flavour, such as this one on [psychometrics and R](http://aliquote.org/memos/2011/02/24/psychoco-2011)
- [G. David Garson](http://faculty.chass.ncsu.edu/garson/PA765/statnote.htm) provides extensive notes on most techniques with a focus on SPSS generally suitable to a psychology research audience.
- [David Kenny](http://davidakenny.net/kenny.htm) has lots of resources particularly on SEM, mediation, moderation, and dyadic data analysis.
- [Encyclopedia - Psychology and Statistics](http://www.psychology.org/links/Resources/Statistics/) has an extensive set of links to resources
- [mathpsych on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/mathpsych/) is a small but interesting Reddit community.

#### A little self-promotion

One of my main aims over the last few years has been to develop resources designed to assist psychology students perform the data analysis for their research. Thus, I hope you'll forgive the self-promotion. The following links may be relevant:

- [Sitemap](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/p/site-map-jeromy-anglims-blog-psychology.html) of the blog. Most of the blog is devoted to saying what I find myself saying to psychology research students in consultation settings. Thus, there's a fair bit of SPSS content in addition to my own preference for R.
- [Advice on completing data analysis for a thesis in psychology](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/05/statistics-for-psychology-thesis.html)
- [General teaching resources with an SPSS manual and some multivariate course notes](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/09/teaching-resources.html)
- [General thoughts on encouraging students to use sites like Cross Validated](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-ask-me-statistics-question.html)

#### R in Psychology

I also have a post on [getting started with R](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/06/learning-r-for-researchers-in.html).

The following quotes the section of that post listing specific resources for researchers in psychology.

- Task Views particularly relevant to psychology

  - [Psychometric Models and Methods](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Psychometrics.html)
  - [Social Sciences](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SocialSciences.html)
  - [Multivariate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Multivariate.html)
- [R Notes for Experimental Psychology](http://artsweb.uwaterloo.ca/~jalockli/R_exp_psy.pdf)
- [William Revelle's
  Psychology R Site](http://www.personality-project.org/R/) ;also see the package ;`pscyh`, ;and the ;[online book and workshop
  resources](http://personality-project.org/r/book/)
- [Jonathan
  Baron and Yelin Li's R for Psychology Experiments](http://www.psych.upenn.edu/~baron/rpsych/rpsych.html)
- [Drew Conway suggests a list of must have R packages for the social
  scientsist](http://www.drewconway.com/zia/?p=1614)
- [SEM in R](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/09/structural-equation-modelling-in-r.html)
- [Mailing
  list for Psychology and R](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A0=PSYCH-R)
- [Edinburgh Psychology R-users](http://psy-ed.wikidot.com/)
- [Jason
  Locklin's notes on standard experimental analyses in psychology](http://artsweb.uwaterloo.ca/~jalockli/R_exp_psy.pdf)
- [My posts with the R tag](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/search/label/R)

Comment: BTW, you may want to add the [psychoR](http://lists.stat.ucla.edu/mailman/listinfo/psychor) mailing, maintained by [Jan de Leeuw](http://www.cuddyvalley.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Copy N' Paste from my Google Reader: http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 3):

- There's a *correct* answer here! 
  http://faculty.chass.ncsu.edu/garson/PA765/statnote.htm
- Also good:

  - http://statcomp.ats.ucla.edu/
  - http://dss.princeton.edu/online_help/
  - http://www.psych.cornell.edu/darlington/

I know you didn't ask, probably because you know, the answer, but absolutely best statistics tests (for multivariate analysis) for psychologists (& for most other social scientists, although they don't all realize it) are:

- Cohen, J., Cohen, P., West, S.G. & Aiken, L.S. Applied Multiple Regression/Correlation Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences, (L. Erlbaum Associates, Mahwah, N.J., 2003).
- Judd, C.M., McClelland, G.H. & Ryan, C.S. Data analysis : a model comparison approach, (Routledge/Taylor and Francis, New York, NY, 2008).

Answer (score 2):

The [UCLA](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/) server has a lot of ressources for statistical computing, including annotated output from various statistical packages.